# Plot frequency of a value of 2 factors in the same plot in R

Tags: r

I'd like to plot the frequency of a variable color coded for 2 factor levels for example blue bars should be the hist of level A and green the hist of level B both n the same graph? Is this possible with the hist command? The help of hist does not allow for a factor. Is there another way around?

I managed to do this by barplots manually but i want to ask if there is a more automatic method

[image]

Many thanks
EC

PS. I dont need density plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the others haven't answered this is a way that satisfies. I had to deal with stacking histograms recently, and here's what I did:

```
data_sub <- subset(data, data$V1 == "Yes") #only samples that have V1 as "yes" in my dataset #are added to the subset

hist(data$HL)
hist(data_sub$HL, col="red", add=T)
```

Hopefully, this is what you meant?

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. Is it possible to draw the bars beside each other?

Comment: On the same graph, you mean? I'm sure that there is, but I don't know how (new to R myself).

Comment: Yeah, on the same graph, side by side

Answer (score 3):

It's rather unclear what you have as a data layout. A histogram requires that you have a variable that is ordinal or continuous so that breaks can be created. If you also have a separate grouping factor you can plot histograms conditional on that factor. A nice worked example of such a grouping and overlaying a density curve is offered in the second example on the help page for the `histogram` function in the lattice package.
[image: Second lattice::histgram example]

A nice resource for learning relative merits of lattice and ggplot2 plotting is the Learning R blog. [This is from the first of a multipart series on side-by=side comparison](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-1/) of the two plotting systems:

```
library(lattice)
 library(ggplot2)
 data(Chem97, package = "mlmRev")
#The lattice method:
pl <- histogram(~gcsescore | factor(score), data = Chem97)
 print(pl)
```

[image: Lattice histogram]

```
# The ggplot method:
 pg <- ggplot(Chem97, aes(gcsescore)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) +
     facet_wrap(~score)
 print(pg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible.

I didn't have data to work with but here's an example of a histogram with different colored bars.  From here you'd need to use my code and figure out how to make it work for factors instead of tails.

BASIC SETUP
histogram <- hist(scale(vector)), breaks= , plot=FALSE)
plot(histogram, col=ifelse(abs(histogram$breaks) < #of SD, Color 1, Color 2))

```
#EXAMPLE
x<-rnorm(1000)
histogram <- hist(scale(x), breaks=20 , plot=FALSE)
plot(histogram, col=ifelse(abs(histogram$breaks) < 2, "red", "green"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that easily with a bar histogram, as you would have to "interlace" the bars from both factor levels... It would need some kind of "discretization" of the now continuous x axis (i.e. it would have to be split in "categories" and in each category you would have 2 bars, for each factor level...

But it is quite easy and without problems if you are just fine with plotting the density line function:

```
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x <- rnorm(1000, 0.5, 2)
dx <- density(x)
dy <- density(y)
plot(dx, xlim = range(dx$x, dy$x), ylim = range(dx$y, dy$y), 
     type = "l", col = "red")
lines(dy, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that a density plot is more useful than merging colored bars of a histogram, particularly if the group's values are intermixed.  This would be very difficult and wouldn't really tell you much.  You've got some great suggestions from others on density plots, here's my 2 cents for density plots that I sometimes use:

```
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1) 
x <- rnorm(1000, 0.5, 2) 
DF <- data.frame("Group"=c(rep(c("y","x"), each=1000)), "Value"=c(y,x))

library(sm)

with(DF, sm.density.compare(Value, Group, xlab="Grouping"))
title(main="Comparative Density Graph")
legend(-9, .4, levels(DF$Group), fill=c("red", "darkgreen"))
```